# Simple Scala program not executing on command prompt

Tags: scala

This is some of the strange issue, the program is only printing hello scala, but it seems that I am getting syntax weird error. Please correct me if I miss anything

Program

```
 object hello{
     def main(args:Array[String]){
            println("Hello Scala")
        }
    }
```

Error:- *'=' expected, but '{' found*

Comment: `def main(args:Array[String]) = {...}` is the correct synthax

Answer (score 3):

As the error message suggests, you need a `=` before the `{`:

```
def main(args: Array[String]) = {
  println("Hello Scala")
}
```

The syntax you used was originally supported so you might see it in some example code. But it was deprecated in later versions and is now no longer allowed.